# how to apply a condition on selected month from datepicker in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to apply a condition on selected date from date picker in html5. i.e. if i have selected jan month and click on submit button it will go to next page and show u were born in jan month.

```
<form action="new.html">
<input type="date"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: date:<input id="t1" type="date"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> it will go to new page

Comment: Could you show us your <form action="..."> tag. It seems like your question is related to server side scripting.

Comment: <form method="post" action="child1.php"><input name="a" type="date">
<input type="submit" value="submit"></form>

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using jquery's datepicker? It will provide your end user a much better experience with the ability to dropdown a calendar and also works in all browsers. Here is the code to do so:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
{
      onSelect: function (arg) {
            var date = new Date(arg);
            // The below code give the index of the month like Jan as 0, ... ,Dec as 11
            var month = date.getMonth();
      }
}
```

And in your body tag,

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

For more info on the jquery datepicker, refer to this link: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker

Here are some good faqs on datepicker if you decide to use it: http://jqfaq.com/category/widgets/datepicker/